# Place pie charts on a map using Basemap

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, charts, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot pie charts on a map using Basemap and Matplotlib.

Do you know a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an axes to a basemap with [inset_axes](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_colorbar_with_inset_locator.html) . I've modified the first example [here](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html) to include a pie chart.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',
            resolution='c',lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.,ax=ax)
# draw coastlines.
m.drawcoastlines()
# draw a boundary around the map, fill the background.
# this background will end up being the ocean color, since
# the continents will be drawn on top.
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
# fill continents, set lake color same as ocean color.
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')

axin = inset_axes(m.ax,width="30%",height="30%", loc=3)
axin.pie([100,200,3000])
plt.show()
```

[image: pie chart on a map]